# Can my PC run ARMA 3?

Tags: pc, arma-3, system-requirements

Is this a good gaming PC? Would it be able to run ARMA 3?

- Intel DG41TY motherboard
- Intel dual core cpu E5200 2.5ghz
- Gigabyte X600 pro graphic cards GPU
- Kingston 2G ram(2x1G)
- WD 80G HDD x2
- Antec ATX cases
- Thermaltake 480W power supply unit
- windows 10 pro English installed and activated

Answer (score 0):

Here are the minimum required specs to run ARMA3:

```
OS  Windows 7 SP1 (64bit) 
PROCESSOR   Intel Dual-Core 2.4 GHz OR AMD Dual-Core Athlon 2.5 GHz
GRAPHICS    NVIDIA GeForce 9800GT OR AMD Radeon HD 5670 OR Intel HD Graphics 4000 with 512 MB VRAM
GPU MEMORY  512 MB
DirectX®    10
RAM 4 GB
HARD DRIVE  20 GB free space
```

Your PC only has 2GB of RAM, 128Mb of GPU Memory, and the GPU is older than the 5670 mentioned.
Even on the lowest settings, your PC will struggle to run ARMA3.